# Output string to look like newspaper article in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, output

I am trying to output a string in the console so that, at a fixed line length, it cuts off and continues the string on a new line - to give the string a newspaper-article look.

**This, I have acheived.** However, I wish to implement a system so that words are not cut off in the middle, disrupting the flow of reading. I would instead like a hyphen inserted at eand of line.

This is the output I currently have:

[image: Picture link]

This is the sort of output I wish to have:

[image: Picture link]

I have tried changing my code on line 9 so it reads as the following, but that results in hyphens being placed at the end of every line -- which isn't what I want.

```
if(outStr[i+1] == " "):
```

How do I alter my code so that it creates the output I would like? This function has to be able to work with any long string, as it will be used multiple times as part of a larger program.

This is the code that I have, written in Python 3.6.5:

```
lorumIpsum = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source."

def OutputStringToBook(outStr):
    # Take each character
    for i in range(len(outStr)):
        # If the character is at the designated line end
        if (i % 30 == 0):
            # If the next character is not a space
            if(outStr[i+1] != " "):
                print()
            else:
                print("-") 
            print(outStr[i], end="")
        else:
            print(outStr[i], end="")
    #time.sleep(0.01)
OutputStringToBook(lorumIpsum)
```

Comment: `range(len(outStr))` is a big-no no in Python (mostly). Use `for ind, i in enumerate(outStr)` instead

Comment: @Agile_Eagle: that link isn't applicable.  OP is able to assign the string just fine; the problem is automated line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it look like a newspaper, you should use a proper hyphenation algorithm.
The [PyHyphen](https://pypi.org/project/PyHyphen/) library includes the hyphenation dictionaries used in libreoffice and supports multiple languages (the default language is `en_US`).

```
# pip install pyhyphen
from hyphen import Hyphenator
from textwrap2 import wrap
english = Hyphenator('en_US')
print('\n'.join(wrap(lorem_text, width=20, use_hyphenator=english)))
```

The output will look like this. Note that some lines are shorter than 20 characters. Hyphens are only used in long words, and follows the language specific rules for hyphenation.

```
Contrary to popular
belief, Lorem Ipsum
is not simply random
text. It has roots
in a piece of clas-
sical Latin litera-
ture from 45 BC,
making it over 2000
years old.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code places a dash at the end of every line because, as it happens, every (30n+1)th character is a non-blank.  First of all, you want to hyphenate *only* when the two line-spanning characters are non-blanks:

```
if(outStr[i] == " " or outStr[i+1] == " "):
```

Now, this still suffers from the problem that you're inserting hyphens without regard for actual syllabic divisions, and you're not eliding spaces at the margins:

```
Contrary to popular belief, Lo-
rem Ipsum is not simply random
 text. It has roots in a piece
 of classical Latin literature
 from 45 BC, making it over 20-
00 years old. Richard McClinto-
ck, a Latin professor at Hampd-
en-Sydney College in Virginia,
 looked up one of the more obs-
cure Latin words, consectetur,
 from a Lorem Ipsum passage, a-
nd going through the cites of -
the word in classical literatu-
re, discovered the undoubtable
```

If you want to remove the marginal spaces, you'll need to do more work: not printing the spaces throws off your position count, which suggests that you'll want to work with a string you consume 30 or 31 chars per line (dependent on removing a leading space).  Making "intelligent" hyphen choices requires a hyphenation dictionary (yes, there is such a thing) and more processing.  Also, adapting to fewer than 30 chars available for a line requires inserting spaces within the line, such as changing

```
rem Ipsum is not simply random
text. It has roots in a piece
```

to

```
rem Ipsum is not simply random
text.  It has roots in a piece
```

This will require somewhat more processing ... if it's worth the effort for your wants.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a direct answer I'm extending Prune's answer with some corrections of your code:

The idea is to remove unnecessary printings and make it more clear.

```
lorumIpsum = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source."
def OutputStringToBook(outStr):
    # Take each character
    for i, item in enumerate(outStr):
        # If the character is at the designated line end
        if (i % 30 == 0):
            # If the current or next character is not a space
            if(item == " " or outStr[i+1] == " "):
                print("-", end='')
            print()
        print(item, end='')

OutputStringToBook(lorumIpsum)
```